# Website does not detect Java on PhantomJS 2.1.1

Tags: c#, phantomjs, headless-browser

I'm trying to just get into the webpage with a Java applet and every single time i run a test on it I get the same prompt which basically says i have no Java on the browser.

The check the site performs is:

```
if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.7+") == false)
```

It always returns false. I tried to change the phantomjs settings with the following script:

```
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
phantom.exit();
```

But the Command Prompt gets stuck. But the option is true by default so I don't think I would change anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java ... Why do you expect PhantomJs to support Java?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Uhm, because it is a java based browser? but now that i see your question my answer might be "because im an idiot".